# MySQL Not getting rows with zero from count and outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, outer-join

For an online game, I have two tables one which lists all breeds(horsebreeds) and the other lists each individual animal(horses) and I am looking to list out the total number of animals of each breed which are alive and owned by a member (owner != 0). I am getting the results for rows which have values but not those which would be a count of zero. I know i need an outer join for this but I must not be structuring it right?

Here is the query:

```
$breedquery = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(H.breed) AS totalbreed, H.breed FROM horses H RIGHT JOIN horsebreeds B ON H.breed = B.breedname WHERE H.owner != 0 GROUP BY H.breed ORDER BY totalbreed DESC");
```

here is a snapshot of the results, as you can see it works to return those with 1 or more but omits breeds with zero

[snapshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKzPM.png)

Thank you for any help with the issue!

Comment: try it with a left join.

Comment: I get identical results with left and right join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` is generally preferable to `RIGHT JOIN` -- ` left join keeps all rows in the first table which is usually simpler to follow.

```
SELECT COUNT(H.breed) AS totalbreed, B.breedname
FROM horsebreeds B LEFT JOIN
     horses H   
     ON H.breed = B.breedname AND H.owner <> 0
GROUP BY B.breedname
ORDER BY totalbreed DESC;
```

Then you need to make two changes:

1. Put the filter on `owner` in the `ON` clause.  Otherwise, you are turning the outer join into an inner join.
2. Use the columns from `horsebreeds` for the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem completely! I will focus on left joins from now on for this kind of approach. A great help you have been @Gordon Linoff